# How to change phpmyadmin's password on config.php.ini use MacOS

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I changed the password on phpmyadmin , then I want to save the new password on config.php.ini, but the system say [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZb3X.png)
,so I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not have permission to write on the file .
That's why you are getting access denied error.

To Solve this error you have to make changes to the permission for the user you currently logged in .

Follow the given steps :

1. Right click on the folder
2. Select Get Info
3. Expand the Sharing & Permission section
4. Unlock the folder by clicking lock icon on bottom right-corner
5. Now, select the user list and enable Read & Write privilege for the
   users
6. Change 'Everyone' permissions to read & write or give permission to your user.

Finally click settings icon and select Apply to enclosed items..

After giving proper read /write permission , Now you can try to change password.

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: this way seems to fail....Finder say I don't have privilege